# Selecting the exact match from xml using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

Below is the sample XML.

```
<segment>
<departure-date-time>2015-01-31T10:40:00</departure-date-time>
<arrival-date-time>2015-01-31T14:00:00</arrival-date-time>
<data-details>
<stop-details>
<arrival-date-time>2015-01-31T12:25:00</arrival-date-time>
<departure-date-time>2015-01-31T13:00:00</departure-date-time>
<layover-duration>2100</layover-duration>
</stop-details>
</data-details>
</segment>
```

I want the  value from the sample XML for that one i wrote

```
$('segment', this).each(function(index, element) {
var arr_tym =$(element).find('arrival-date-time').text();
var dst_tym =$(element).find('departure-date-time').text();
});
```

If i use like this i am getting the result, but it is taking the value of

also and printing as **2015-01-31T14:00:002015-01-31T12:25:00**

actual output should be **2015-01-31T14:00:00.** . I want all these values .

```
<departure-date-time>2015-01-31T10:40:00</departure-date-time>
<arrival-date-time>2015-01-31T14:00:00</arrival-date-time>
```

I dont want values inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then what about using this in the loop ?

```
var dep = $(element).find('departure-date-time')[0].innerHTML;
var arr = $(element).find('arrival-date-time')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you're using jQuery on XML data, replacing `$('segment', this)` by `$('segment > departure-date-time', this)` should do the trick here, and simplify the second part, as it will directly select the only first `departure-date-time` in your `segment` :

```
$('segment > departure-date-time, segment > arrival-date-time', this).each(function(index, element) {
    var text=$(element).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: i want the first one --->  <segment><departure-date-time>this value only</departure-date-time></segment>, not inside the <data-details>

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer, it should work now

Comment: cannt we make anything on this one $(element).find('arrival-date-time').text(); because there are so many values in the <segment>. Please give me some what clear explaination because i am new on this please !!!!

Comment: @sivashanker I think you should edit your question to clarify what is your sample data and what exactly do you want from it

Comment: Actually my problem is if i use like this $('segment > departure-date-time, segment > departure-date-time', this).each(function(index, element) { }); it will be applicable only for departure-date-time, can we able to make anything on this $(element).find('arrival-date-time').text(),$(element).find('departure-date-time').text() only on this !!!

Comment: @sivashanker Yeah sorry, this was a typo. Should be `'segment > departure-date-time, segment > arrival-date-time'` instead of `'segment > departure-date-time, segment > departure-date-time'`

Comment: i got ur point, one small thing here is $('segment', this).each(function(index, element)  is already looping up so, now without using $('segment > departure-date-time, segment > arrival-date-time', this).each(function(index, element)  as u mentioned above can we do anything on $(element).find('arrival-date-time').text(); so that i can get the above posted output . Please help with this because i cannot make looping again on segment. because like arrivaldate, departure date there are 100's of xml tags inside